# Mysql how to Count rows and group by value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get this simple query to work. I like to know how many times a certain vouchercode has been used and what the total discount value is per used voucher code.

The database table has fields `discount_value`, `discount_data`. The `discount_data` holds the vouchercode and `discount_value` the sum of discount per purchase id.

```
SELECT discount_data, 
       COUNT(*) 
  FROM wp_wpsc_purchase_logs 
GROUP BY 
       discount_data
```

seems to work to get amount of voucher code used.

But how do i get the total discount_value per used voucher code?

regards

Comment: `SUM(discount_value)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Is the `SUM()` function what you are looking for?

```
SELECT discount_data, COUNT(*), SUM(discount_value)
FROM wp_wpsc_purchase_logs 
GROUP BY discount_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum() function may be

```
SELECT discount_data, SUM(discount_value), count(*)
FROM wp_wpsc_purchase_logs 
GROUP BY discount_data
```